Explicit Examples for Unrestricted Hartree Fock Calculations
I am currently working on writing a Hartree Fock program in C++, currently using the STO-3G  basis set. My program works well for the restricted case, but I am running into some issues with the unrestricted case. It works for unrestricted calculations with $N^{\alpha}=N^{\beta}$, but it is failing for $N^{\alpha}\neq N^{\beta}$ and I cannot seem to find the source of the issue (it strangely is reporting $N^{\beta}$ negative alpha orbital energies and $N^{\alpha}$ negative beta orbital energies).
I have been looking for examples of UHF calculations but I cannot seem to find any thorough examples. Many resources have well flushed out examples for RHF (such as Szabo & Ostlund, or this example calculation for H2O).
Are there any good resources for UHF like this? I asked a similar question on the chemistry stack exchange, although this was moreso asking to verify if my procedure was correct, which it generally seems to be. I am now just looking for examples.
Thanks!
Edit: By request, the code may be found here. Note that everything works fine for the restricted case and there seems to be no issues with the basis functions, integrals, or other low level routines. The issue seems to be only with the unrestricted case; the code for UHF is localized entirely within /main/hartree-fock.cpp and /libscf/scfuhf.cpp. There are also many sample inputs/outputs in /main/, as well as a failed CH3 run.

Do you have your current code on Github/Gitlab? You can include a link along with your question. From the Chem SE question, it seems like you have the right concept for UHF, but that something was wrong in translating it to code.

@Tyberius Yes, perhaps I should have included that. I have edited my post to include a GitHub link.

Just from a quick glance, it looks like you have the alpha and beta density in the wrong places when forming the alpha and beta Fock matrix here

@Tyberius Thanks for taking a look. The function corresponds to the equation for the Fock matrix in my post on Chemistry SE, so the pb in the expression for fa is the one that gets subtracted, which I believe is still correct.

In my copy of Szabo and Ostlund, the UHF Fock matrix expression are equations 3.348 and 3.349. In each of these, a term depending on the same spin density (P^a for F^a, P^b for F^b) is subtracted from a term depending on the total density. So I think your equation from the Chem SE post might be incorrect and it should be P^a rather than P^b.

@Tyberius I guess this is a testament to working out every equation myself from now on, I do not know how I did not see that. Thank you so much!

Thanks for everyone’s help. As it turns out, I was simply using the wrong density matrices to construct the corresponding Fock matrices, and I was summing over the total electrons both times instead of the alpha/beta electrons for each sum in the expression for the $\langle S^2 \rangle$ value. Everything now works fine.

Writing your own SCF program is a great way to learn about the basic tools and concepts used in electronic structure theory. There are many resources/codes online that you can use to compare implementations and outputs. Here are just a few:
ERKALE (see scf files)
PySCF
psi4numpy
Adrian Roman's Hartree-Fock repository
Regarding your previous post on the Chemistry SE, you may need to confirm that both the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ density matrices are formed properly in your UHF routine. This is necessary for obtaining orbitals, orbital energies, total energies, populations, etc. in a correct manner.
You also mention that you want to compute the total spin-squared expectation value
$\langle\mathcal{S}^2\rangle = S_z(S_z + 1) + N_{\beta} - \sum\limits_{i\overline{j}}^{N_{occ}} |\mathbb{S}_{i\overline{j}}|^{2}$
This value should not be smaller than the exact $S_z(S_z + 1)$, though it can certainly be larger for high-spin or open-shell singlet solutions. Ensure that the summation in the third term containing the $\alpha\beta$ MO overlap runs over the occupied indices. Note that the usual convention for odd electron count has $N_\alpha \gt N_\beta$ for when $N_\alpha \ne N_\beta$. These few points may help ameliorate the issues discussed in your previous post.
Furthermore, the results in this paper may also assist with your code validation.
For anything beyond minimal basis with s and p orbitals, you may want to obtain the AO integrals from some other quantum chemistry program or find a way to port an efficient integral engine. If you are feeling particularly adventurous, you can create your own. Introductory references by M Hô & JM Hernández-Pérez, PMW Gill, and JT Fermann & EF Valeev may be helpful if you choose to go this route.

Thank you for all of this, I will check through that paper to see if it helps. I was able to make some progress regarding the <S^2> value; it is now greater than the exact spin for the methyl radical but is still lower than the value reported by Szabo/Ostlund. As for the integrals, there seems to be no issue there; I was able to implement the recursive McMurchie-Davidson scheme from scratch (I actually did use the paper by Fermann and Valeev you linked for part of it).
